# Fonts in Version 11.2: Source Sans Pro instead of Arial for Headlines and Text

Tags: formatting

After installing version 11.2 I noticed that the standard styles for all headlines and text have been changed from Arial to Source Sans Pro (SSp). 
Does anyone have an idea why this is the case?

- **Why did they change the fonts for headlines and text cells?**
- **What is the advantage of SSp with respect to Arial?**
- **Is Ssp available on all computers?** I never took notice of that font before.
- **Will Mma  notebooks made on a Windows PC look the same when they are opened on a Linux PC?**

Letters in SSp seem to be smaller than the same letters in Arial. Also SSp is lighter than Arial. For headlines semibold looks comparable to Arial with standard weight.

Since letters in SSp are smaller and not as wide as their counterparts, definition for indented paragraphs must be adapted to get an appearance as before (this is related to the notorious issue of TabSpaces being defined in ems, the width of a capital M, whereas ParagraphIndent has to be given in printer's points. Since the width of the capital M changes from one font to another, this can cause quite some headache).